# SAS: Output last value across several by-groups

Tags: sas

I want to output the last value of a variable pr. sub-group to a SAS dataset, preferably in just a few steps. The code below do it, but I was hoping to do it in one step a la `by variable; if last.variable then output;` as for the case with just 1 by-variable.

```
data two;
input year firm price;
cards;
1 1 48    
1 1 45
2 2 50
1 2 42
2 1 41
2 2 51
2 1 52
1 1 43
1 2 52;
run;
proc sort data = two;by year firm;run;

/* a) Create id across both sub-groups */
data two1;
set two;
by year firm;
retain case_id;
if FIRST.year OR first.firm then case_id + 1;
run;

/* b) Use id to output last values across both by-groups */
data two2;
set two1;
by case_id;
if last.case_id then output;
run;

proc print data = two1;run;
proc print data = two2;run;
```

With just 1 by-variable the two steps marked a) and b) can be combined. Is it possible with more than one by-group?

Comment: Note that the first/last record for the outer group is always also the first/last record for one of the inner groups.  So `first.year OR first.firm` can be reduced to `first.firm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In data step a) add condition `if lst.firm then output two2`.

The final code should looks like:

```
data two1 two2;
   set two;
   by year firm;
   retain case_id;
   if FIRST.year OR first.firm then case_id + 1;
   if last.firm then output two2;
   output two1;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I only created the `case_id` because of step b) in my post. So since I really don't need the `if last.firm then output;` will do. Does it work because `firm` is 2nd in the by-statement, and then relative to the first by-variable (hence `last` is within groups defined by first by-variable)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Because `firm` is 2nd in by-statement after `year' it becames a sub-group for `year` group. So when the `year` value is changed it also set flags first and last for `firm` variable. So when flag `last.firm` is set, that means that one of variables `year` or `firm` is changing it's value in next record.